# Why is git send-email reporting "died" after successful authentication?

Tags: git, git-send-email

Using git 2.5.

When I use *git send-email* to send a patch, I'm seeing the following error output:

`Died at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-send-email line 1348.`

Here's the output of `git send-email --smtp-debug=1 -1`.

```
Send this email? ([y]es|[n]o|[q]uit|[a]ll): y
Net::SMTP>>> Net::SMTP(3.08)
Net::SMTP>>>   Net::Cmd(3.08)
Net::SMTP>>>     Exporter(5.72)
Net::SMTP>>>   IO::Socket::IP(0.37)
Net::SMTP>>>     IO::Socket(1.38)
Net::SMTP>>>       IO::Handle(1.35)
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1be69c8)<<< 220 mail.example.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.2/8.14.2/; Thu, 10 Mar 2016 19:18:24 GMT
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1be69c8)>>> EHLO myhost-localdomain.localdomain
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1be69c8)<<< 250-mail.example.com Hello [5.5.5.42], pleased to meet you
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1be69c8)<<< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1be69c8)<<< 250-8BITMIME
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1be69c8)<<< 250-SIZE 52428800
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1be69c8)<<< 250-AUTH CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1be69c8)<<< 250-STARTTLS
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1be69c8)<<< 250 HELP
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1be69c8)>>> STARTTLS
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1be69c8)<<< 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
Net::SMTP::SSL=GLOB(0x1be69c8)>>> EHLO myhost-localdomain.localdomain
Net::SMTP::SSL=GLOB(0x1be69c8)<<< 250-mail.example.com Hello [5.5.5.42], pleased to meet you
Net::SMTP::SSL=GLOB(0x1be69c8)<<< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Net::SMTP::SSL=GLOB(0x1be69c8)<<< 250-8BITMIME
Net::SMTP::SSL=GLOB(0x1be69c8)<<< 250-SIZE 52428800
Net::SMTP::SSL=GLOB(0x1be69c8)<<< 250-AUTH CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN
Net::SMTP::SSL=GLOB(0x1be69c8)<<< 250 HELP
Net::SMTP::SSL=GLOB(0x1be69c8)>>> AUTH DIGEST-MD5
Net::SMTP::SSL=GLOB(0x1be69c8)<<< 334 bm9uY2U9Ik1oa2NLc0h...Nz
Net::SMTP::SSL=GLOB(0x1be69c8)>>> YXV0aHppZD0iYWMyOTI2MCI...==
Net::SMTP::SSL=GLOB(0x1be69c8)<<< 334 cnNwYXV0aD0yMDMxOTB...==
Net::SMTP::SSL=GLOB(0x1be69c8)>>> 
Net::SMTP::SSL=GLOB(0x1be69c8)<<< 235 2.0.0 OK Authenticated
Net::SMTP::SSL=GLOB(0x1be69c8)>>> MAIL FROM:<me@example.com>
Died at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-send-email line 1348.
```

According to the debug output, it seems my git config is correct and I successfully authenticate. So... any idea why the email isn't being sent and I'm seeing the "Died" message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above error occurs with git 2.5. After upgrading to 2.7, the issue no longer occurs.